# Reinstall Ubuntu keep Windows (dual boot, GNU Grub)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, reinstall

I need to reinstall Ubuntu after something went wrong, and there is only a black screen showing after the Ubuntu login page. Running a dual boot system with Gnu Grub, and Windows on a different partition. Would like to keep Windos and the Gnu Grub layout.
Downloaded Ubuntu and created a USB drive using Rufus, but even though I changed the boot order in BIOS and connected the USB drive, the system jumps to Gnu grub without the option of loading from the USB drive.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should create a bootable USB stick from another system (there are various methods but if you use windows I highly recommend using YUMi, if Linux, then some old version of UNetBootin that supports iso files), then select you pendrive as the media you want to boot from in PC's setup (generally pressing F2 or DEL right after powering your PC On).

Comment: Now as for the any grub related boot issues see the boot repair tool, it's much more easy than trying to fix it manually https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

The advantage about Linux, the solution is not always reinstalling. You have a rescue Shell, which it is the tool to repair blank screen (graphics driver and Xorg) you should search about your graphics card and Ubuntu.